# How to make this portlet collapsed by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following portlet code. However it is shown expanded. How can I show it (by default) as collapsed?

```
<div id="myPortlet" data-pages="portlet" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading ">
        <div class="panel-title">Portlet Title
        </div>
        <div class="panel-controls">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="portlet-collapse" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="portlet-icon portlet-icon-collapse"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's a portlet? `panel-collapse` will collapse a regular BS panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the class `panel-collapsed` to the outer div

```
<div id="myPortlet" data-pages="portlet" class="panel panel-default panel-collapsed">
```

and also add in your CSS the following rule

```
.panel-collapsed > .panel-body{
    display: none
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this `style="display: none;"` to the portlet-body line, and change the collapse anchor too

```
<div id="myPortlet" data-pages="portlet" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading ">
        <div class="panel-title">Portlet Title
        </div>
        <div class="panel-controls">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="expand" data-original-title="" title=""></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="display:none;">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried this, however it does not behave well when i click and re-click it

Comment: Which template you have ?

Comment: Did you change the anchor which inside the panel-controls?